# What's difference between 'have' and 'have got'?

Tags: word-choice

For example,

1) I think you have a wrong number.

2) I think you've got a wrong number.

Is there any difference between the two sentences above?

Comment: Check out these links: [link1](http://speakspeak.com/grammar-articles/which-should-we-use-have-or-have-got-2) , [link2](http://www.oneworldofenglish.com/english_grammar_reference/have_and_have_got.htm) , [link3](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/120721/have-vs-have-got-in-american-and-british-english)

Comment: Thank you! Are the following sentences also same during the phone call?
1) I have John here.
 2) I've got John here.

Comment: I don't think you can use _have got_ instead of _have_ in this case. In the link1 i addressed, check out number 5 explanation. when you say **i have john here**, you mean **you are hosting john**. in this case that you are using _have_ instead of verb _host_, you can't use have got. Note that I am not completely sure about my answer. you can ask somebody else.

Comment: Idiomatically there are certainly contexts where almost nobody would do without "got-support". For example, *"At last! I'm glad to see you have [you've] **got** my point!"*. Where I suppose it's feasible something like that might have been said a century or two ago, but I don't think it would ever work today.

Comment: What does 'I am hosting John.' mean? I thought 'I have John here.' means 'I have John with me here.'. Is my thought correct?

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in meaning between **have** and **have got**, specially in your sentence.

The only difference between them is that **have** is used in formal written English (and of course in spoken English) and **have** **got** is used in spoken English.

Comment: If I use 'have' in spoken English, does it sound too formal?

Comment: as far as i know, the answer is No. it is very common to use _have_.

Comment: 'Have' is standard, neutral English, I don't think it could come across as too formal. 'Got' is also very common, but has a slight informality to it.

Comment: Usage varies not only with register but also dialect and even (believe it or not) by the sex of the speaker, at least in the US.

Comment: Yes, this answer is missing some fairly important information about dialects.

Answer (score 1):

**I have got** is typically British.  It is rarely heard in AmE, except as the contraction "I've got".

As for the "must" sense: I have got to...[do something] becomes, in AmE, "I've got to", 
which comes out  sounding like

- **I gotta** [do something].

Or, "I have to" [do something]
 which comes out as

- **I hafta** [do something].

Answer (score 0):

To add to the comments above, to "get" something is to acquire it.  The reason that *I have* has a roughly equivalent meaning to *I have got* (or often *I've got* or even *I got*) is because one may be presumed to have acquired something that one has.

The difference between the two can be significant in some circumstances, for example when *got* is used as an alternate form of *gotten*:

> I have got sick.
>   I have gotten sick.

This means that I have become sick, and *I have sick* isn't correct at all.  The second usage is currently more popular than the first, but they go back and forth regularly over time.

Comment: *Got* is the usual form of the past participle in BrE.

Comment: That makes sense.  I guess I heard it over there more than over here.  :)